# Does "2 years into a person's employment" sound right?

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I am trying to say a person would normally be considered for promotion at their second year of employment. Does the following sound correct?

- Generally a person would be considered for promotion 2 years **into** his employment at XXX company.
- Generally a person would be considered for promotion 2 years **into** working at XXX company.

Does the use of *into* in the phrase make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but a more common way of saying it would be "after two years of working at" or "after two years of employment at".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does work.

Although, to be fair, it isn't a very commonly used phrase.

You'd be better off using something along the lines of "B years worked at the company" or "has been working at the company for B years".

It's just more commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds fine. And "X years into a project/job/mission... etc. are also OK.